# Inner interface classes?

Tags: java, class, interface

Are class that are declared inside and interface automatically declared static? I am aware that variables are automatically declared static final. I'm just unsure as to interfaces.

Comment: static means that it doesn't belong to an instance of a class, so a 'static' class doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Hunter: No, `static` means it does not belong with any specific instance. :-)

Comment: @Chris, correct I was typing quickly and left out doesn't, my bad I will fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a Class is declared inside an Interface then it is static.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need to know but didn't want to hear. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.5):

> A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly static and
>   public